# How can I get multiple values from string using SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Tags: mysql, string, indexing, split, substring

I have a table where I extract some values, one column values can contain

```
'FLSD202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT'
```

I want to split them become

```
FLSD202 AS first column
-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN AS Second column
/UM/H7/SCT AS third column
```

here my script but i can't get the result as i want

```
SELECT 'FLSD202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('FLXA202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT', '-',1), '-', -1) FirstColumn, 
CONCAT('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('FLSD202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT', '/',1), '/', -1), '-',-1)) SecondColumn,
CONCAT('/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('FLSD202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT', '/',3), '/', -1)) ThirdColumn
```

I want to use this for ALL values, not just one field..

And the `'-'`(dash) is dynamic and `'/'`(slash) is dynamic, ex :
`SSS145-SS3/POP, KEEE-CDE0/NO/SA, WXAE-C-D/E/G, SAD-SEU-SFX/OPS`

Thanks

Comment: To fulfill this you need to make a procedure.

Comment: Some tasks are better done in application code instead of SQL.

Comment: I agree with @RickJames, just fetch the string into Python or Ruby or PHP or *any other language* and the task becomes trivial. If you don't like to do that, then don't store a single string for data that should be separate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will help you to complete your requirement.

```
SET @a = 'FLSD202-D-B-D-AB-C1-NN-A-N-LA-J-NN/UM/H7/SCT';
SET @dash_start_position = LOCATE('-',@a); 
SET @slash_start_position = LOCATE('/',@a);
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, 1, @dash_start_position-1) as First, IF(@slash_start_position IS NOT NULL AND @slash_start_position > 0, SUBSTRING(@a, @dash_start_position, @slash_start_position - @dash_start_position), SUBSTRING(@a, @dash_start_position)) as Second,SUBSTRING(@a, @slash_start_position) as Third;
```

Comment: Hi @Jack, this code is running as well but i testing with 'POOOO-90'  using the Second giving me blank. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I modified Please verify.